# Como usar o generics com as props de um componente?

Tags: typescript, react

Estou tentando criar um componente que ele vai aceitar um tipo genérico dentro das `props`. Estou tentando fazer da seguinte forma:

```
interface Props<T> {
  items: T[];
}

const componente: React.FC<Props<T>> = (props) => {...}
```

Entretanto, dessa forma ele retorna um erro dizendo que `T` não foi definido. Qual seria a forma correta de criar um componente com props genéricas?

Comment: Felipe, estava lendo uma PR no GitHub e acabei me lembrando desta pergunta: https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/pull/8177

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basta utilizar como um genérico de funções normal, o TypeScript entenderá que se trata de um componente React quando você o chamar.

Assim:

```
interface Props<T> {
  items: T[];
}

//                  ↓↓↓
function MyComponent<T>(props: Props<T>) {
  return (
    <>{JSON.stringify(props.items, null, 2)}</>
  );
}
```

Note que você não poderá utilizar uma *arrow function* utilizando o tipo `React.FC`, já que o genérico teria que vir *depois*. O tipo `React.FC` adiciona a propriedade `children` de modo implícito. Desse modo, se o seu componente tiver que usar essa *prop*, basta modificar a interface `Props`:

```
interface Props<T> {
  items: T[];
  children: React.ReactNode;
}
```

Para *definir* o genérico no componente, utilize esta notação:

```
<MyComponent<string> items={['A', 'B', 'C']} />
<MyComponent<number> items={[1, 2, 3]} />
```

No final, você terá algo como:

```
import React from 'react';

interface Props<T> {
  items: T[];
}

function MyComponent<T>(props: Props<T>) {
  return (
    <>{JSON.stringify(props.items, null, 2)}</>
  );
}

function MainComponent() {
  return (
    <> 
      <MyComponent<string> items={['A', 'B', 'C']} />
      <MyComponent<number> items={[1, 2, 3]} />
    </>
  );
}
```

Veja funcionando no [TypeScript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAJQKYEMDG8BmUIjgcilQ3wG4BYAKCuADsYkpN0k4AFHMAZwB4AVAHxwA3lThxgDEFwBccPgG0AuhUoBfKlUwBXWhmARacALIBPAMK5ItJPX4CAFGE6z2L%20wEoRYuERjaoIwcfcR4BYQApAGUAeQA5ADouGCg6AHNgTFMnFwTJJGkAGjhabQAbMuKAJg81HgB6AR8PVQ1qSh09GAMjYxQ6S3BDWxgHL1FKcT8AoJC4MLg50LNB6xGeZNTaNKF86QBeYQV8AEF8YvwAIXOCc3wlNThGpfmVq2G7UpAAI0ZdqS4hwUAEZqsUAMwPJ5NSbiebPWEtKhqIA).

Comment: Teria como o MyComponent ser uma arrow function?

Comment: Sim, mas você não poderia usar o tipo `React.FC`, já que o genérico do componente viria _depois_ do tipo que você passaria para o genérico de `React.FC`.

Comment: @FelipeAvelar, faltou alguma informação na resposta?

Comment: Não, não, queria ver se alguém mais respondia antes de aceitar, mas parece que não vai ter mais ninguém :/