# Alteração de classe para função

Tags: javascript, typescript, react

Quero transformar a seguinte classe em uma função:

```
class Basic extends Component<Props, State>
```

A minha dúvida é: como passo as propriedades props e state para a função?

Comment: você está usando `typescript`?

Comment: sim, porém não entendo quase nada

Comment: O estado em componentes funcionais não está atrelado à instância da função, portanto não há porquê para tipar o estado na função, como é feito nas classes. Tente **[edit]** a sua pergunta para adicionar mais informações?

Comment: @LuizFelipe indiretamente sim ...eu posso tipar o estado.

Comment: @VirgilioNovic, sim, você pode tipar o estado, mas o tipo do estado não está atrelado à instância da função (assim como está para as classes)...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Tipando `props`

Como `props` são passadas como o primeiro parâmetro para componentes funcionais pelo React, basta colocar os devidos tipos para o primeiro parâmetro. Geralmente, cria-se uma [`interface`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/interfaces.html) para isso:

```
import React from 'react';

interface Props {
  name: string;
  age: number;
}

export function UserCard(props: Props) {
  return <>{/* ... */}</>;
}
```

Você também pode utilizar o tipo [`React.FC`](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/843feeed9961898fc2d73dc80dba3502f6608386/types/react/index.d.ts#L554), exportado pelo React:

```js
import React from 'react';

interface Props {
  name: string;
  age: number;
}

export const UserCard: React.FC<Props> = (props) => {
  return <>{/* ... */}</>;
};
```

No entanto, por preferência pessoal, prefiro não usar *arrow functions* para esse tipo de coisa. Conforme pode ser verificado [nesta resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/451018/como-usar-o-generics-com-as-props-de-um-componente/451034#451034), componentes com declarações de funções têm algumas vantagens se comparados a *arrow functions*.

---

### Tipando `state`

Como o estado em componentes funcionais é alcançado através dos [React Hooks](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-intro.html), você não adiciona os tipos do estado diretamente na função do componente, mas nas próprias chamadas dos ganchos. Na maioria das vezes, isso é feito com [genéricos](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/generics.html).

Geralmente, os ganchos da API do React inferem automaticamente o tipo do estado através do primeiro argumento. Veja como passar um tipo explícito para um `useState`, por exemplo:

```js
import React, { useState } from 'react';

export function MyComponent() {
  const [bool, setBool] = useState<boolean>(false);

  setBool(true); // ok
  setBool('foo'); // Argument of type '"foo"' is not assignable to parameter of type 'SetStateAction<boolean>'.

  return <code>{bool.toString()}</code>
}
```

<sup>Veja o exemplo acima no [TypeScript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAJQKYEMDGMA0cDecCuAzkgMowoxJwC%20cAZlBCHAORSoYsDcAsAFD8kAD0ix6%20AHYZgECXACyATwDCTSBKQSYACgCUufnDhpZheAG0ARhAgAbbMRgAhG7YC6cALwFiZCkgAeaztUCQA%20bToUW2JdXj4jQzhHFzttGCh8JDi4AHpcuAgAaySU120WOhsWHPy4AEEoAHN8EE14CDo4GEUwKhYAIiqIAZY4YEI4CQh4FEJCYCaJFEtbKhgIODAUKBQ2yihCrp6%201hIkGD9KeulZINdQsJYAOn4k9hh8KDkAkwATJBhHDBWzPDZkKDACRNPTUAK5f6A-jUIA).</sup>

Atualmente, não consta na documentação do React a explicação de como usar esses genéricos. No entanto, você pode verificar as [definições de tipo do React](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/types/react/index.d.ts) no GitHub.